# Fetch hourly data

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.4

I am calculating the hour delta as below

```
ct = time.time() * 1000 // milliseconds
pt = ct - (1000*60*60*1) // 1 hour
```

The above code will give me the hour timestamp. How can I use the above code to get the past 20 days data hour by hour?

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

times = [datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=n) for n in range(24*20)]   #±smh like this